# convert word to letter

Tags: python

Code:

```py
mapping = {'hello':'a', 'world':'b'}
string = 'helloworld'
out = ' '.join(mapping.get(s,s) for s in string.split())
print(out)
```

What I want to happen is that `string = 'helloworld'`gets printed as `ab`

What I get as the output is `'helloworld'`

The reason is I don't have a space between the string `hello` and `world` but I don't want a space in-between them. Can anyone help?

Comment: ```string.split()``` splits the string using the ' ' as separator.  There's no space in your ```string``` so nothing gets separated.  But since you don't want to have a space in ```string```, there's little point in using ```split()```.

Answer (score 1):

A crude solution in this case would be to simply replace according to the mapping.

```
def replace(string, mapping):
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        string = string.replace(k, v)
    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the output `helloworld` because `string.split()` from your code returns `'helloworld'`, which is what you already had to start with. The `split` does nothing because split, by default, will split a string by a space; of which there are none in your string.

```
>>>'helloworld'.split()
['helloworld']
```

If you change the following line, you will get `a b` as your output.

```
string = 'hello world'
```

I am going to assume that you say that you "don't want a space in between them", you mean that you don't want a space between `a` and `b`. To achieve that, change the following line:

```
out = ''.join(mapping.get(s,s) for s in string.split())
```

This will output `ab`

Comment: "I don't have a space between the string hello and world but I don't want a space in-between them" I read this as they want to be able to solve this for the string 'helloworld' without adding a space between "hello and world"

Comment: @HenryEcker I read it like that at first too, but then I thought about it for a moment and thought that "the reason" for that output (referenced in the line before) was because there is no space in between `hello` and `world`, which is true. If OP clarifies that this is the case, "I don't want a space between them" would refer to printing `ab` instead of `helloworld`.

Comment: Okay. My interpretation still is that string "helloworld" should become "ab" (_i.e._ the ability to find substring matches should not be predicated on the existence of a space). The current method does not work because there is no space between "hello" and "world". The problem that needs solved is how can to find these substrings _without_ adding a space between "hello" and "world". That said, I agree the question is sufficiently unclear for me to defend that position further.

Comment: @HenryEcker, I think that's a valid way to interpret the question as it currently is worded.  I actually considered including an answer for that interpretation in my answer as well. Perhaps if I have a moment a little later I will edit my answer accordingly.